How to use answers of parsers when nesting parsers (sequentially)
This is my Parser
data Parser a = MkParser (String -> Maybe (String, a))
This is a parser that parses if a particular predicate holds true.
satisfy :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
-- takes a predicate (takes a item and gives True or False)
-- Nothing if it's False, parse if it's true
satisfy pred = MkParser sf
    where
        sf (c:cs) | pred c = Just (cs, c)
        sf _ = Nothing

This parser simply gives what I want and doesn't change the input string:
pure :: a -> Parser a
pure a = MkParser sf
    where
        sf inp = Just (inp, a)

Now I have this parser. It takes a parser, and the answer is given to a function that parses based on the answer given.
dsc :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
dsc (MkParser pa) pb = MkParser sf
    where
        sf inp = case pa inp of
            Nothing -> Nothing
            Just (cs, c) -> unParser (pb c) cs


-- this just runs a parser
unParser :: Parser a -> String -> Maybe (String, a)
unParser (MkParser pa) inp = pa inp

Now, I'm trying to parse a string. If it's a letter, then a digit, then I want to give the letter and the digit:
myldV2 :: Parser String
myldV2 = dsc (dsc (satisfy isAlpha) (\x-> satisfy isDigit)) (\y -> pure [x,y])

But it says x is out of range. My solution was to recreate it like this, and it does work (basically I made it an inline parser): Understanding bracket use in Haskell - Parser that depends on previous parser gives error when using brackets
My second solution works too:
lde = dsc p1 f1
    where
        p1 = satisfy isAlpha
        f1 x = dsc p2 f2
            where
                p2 = satisfy isDigit
                f2 y = dsc p3 f3
                    where
                        p3 = char '!'
                        f3 = \_ -> pure [x,y]

But how do I get my first attempted solution to work? This one myldV2 = dsc (dsc (satisfy isAlpha) (\x-> satisfy isDigit)) (\y -> pure [x,y])
I basically want to know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it so I better understand Haskell and what's going on . Thank you.

satisfy isAlpha \dsc` \ x -> satisfy isDigit `dsc` \ y -> pure [x,y]. Or make ParseraMonadand usedo`-notation. The compiler tells you what's wrong so I'm not sure what more information you want.

You'll need to do the nesting inside the pb function: dsc (satisfy isAlpha) (\x-> dsc (satisfy isDigit) (\y -> pure [x,y]))

Simply inline things in your second solution and you'll get one that looks very much like your first solution. In small steps, here's the starting point:
lde = dsc p1 f1
    where
        p1 = satisfy isAlpha
        f1 x = dsc p2 f2
            where
                p2 = satisfy isDigit
                f2 y = dsc p3 f3
                    where
                        p3 = char '!'
                        f3 = \_ -> pure [x,y]

Inline p3 and f3:
lde = dsc p1 f1
    where
        p1 = satisfy isAlpha
        f1 x = dsc p2 f2
            where
                p2 = satisfy isDigit
                f2 y = dsc (char '!') (\_ -> pure [x,y])

Inline p2 and f2:
lde = dsc p1 f1
    where
        p1 = satisfy isAlpha
        f1 x = dsc (satisfy isDigit) (\y -> dsc (char '!') (\_ -> pure [x,y]))

Inline p1 and f1:
lde = dsc (satisfy isAlpha) (\x -> dsc (satisfy isDigit) (\y -> dsc (char '!') (\_ -> pure [x,y])))

If you like, you can make some of the repeated structure here more visible with some artistic whitespace. I'll also swap parens for $, just to avoid the close parens at the end that spoil the extensibility.
lde = dsc (satisfy isAlpha) $ \x ->
      dsc (satisfy isDigit) $ \y ->
      dsc (char '!') $ \_ ->
      pure [x,y]

Hopefully the connection with the standard do-notation version pops out at you! Your dsc is very like (>>=), and if you actually named it that you could write this to mean the same thing:
lde = do
    x <- satisfy isAlpha
    y <- satisfy isDigit
    char '!' -- OR, if you want to be explicit about it: _ <- char '!'
    pure [x,y]


Use this code pattern, where dsc is applied infix for extra conveience:
p :: Parser SomeType
p =
  parser1 `dsc` \ x1 ->
  parser2 `dsc` \ x2 ->
  ...
  parserN `dsc` \ xN ->
  pure (someFunction x1 ... xN)

With explicit parentheses, it reads as:
p :: Parser SomeType
p =
  parser1 `dsc` (\ x1 ->
  parser2 `dsc` (\ x2 ->
  ...
  parserN `dsc` (\ xN ->
  pure (someFunction x1 ... xN)
  )...))

Note how the first \ x1 -> ... makes the scope of x1 reach the very end of the expression. The other lambdas similarly make the scope of their bound variable end at the last line of code.
You can rewrite the above using dsc in prefix position, if you prefer. Yet, for a monadic-like operator like dsc, it is somehow idiomatic to use action `dsc` \ result -> .... when do notation can not be used.
